# Virtual device when started in Genymotion Hangs (Force Close) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, android

My Ubuntu 12.04 `uname -a` is as follows,

```
Linux XXX-XXXXXXXX 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:04:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I have Installed Virtual Box, version is,

**4.1.12_Ubuntur77245**

My Genymotion Version is :

**Version 2.2.2**

When I Start Genymotion, everything is ok and runs perfectly.
But when I start a specific Virtual Device, The Emulator just **Freezes**, If I close the emulator I get a "Force Close".

I am not finding what the problem is. The default Android Virtual Device is very slow.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

-just a quick heads up!
Genymotion will NOT work with the standard open-source drivers! (not properly anyway!)
You need to install the proprietary graphic card drivers.

For example;
under Additional Drivers in Ubuntu, you will find all available/compatiblie drivers, both open and closed

Good Luck!